# Steps to edit HTML from a mobile device

Tags: android, database, request

I've made a calendar in HTML that I was planning on being able to edit from my phone; the purpose of which being to type entries on my phone and be able to look at them in my calendar from my computer. Is this possible, and, if so, what is the most time and resource efficient method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of phone you have?

Comment: I have a Galaxy S7.